# How to get the processor name and registered to informations using java?

Tags: java, system-information

How we can get the processor name and registered to informations from PC?  How is it possible through Java? I'm using windows OS.

Refer this image.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "registered to informations from PC"? Do you mean the registration information from the OS installation? Please elaborate, and specify what OS(es) you have in mind.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: @Sleske:See [here](http://blog.joeware.net/wp-content/uploads/2006/12/WindowsLiveWriter/IaddedmyworklaptoptomyhomedomainandnowI_96FD/SystemProperties_thumb.gif). Im asking for windows PC.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please edit your question to include the new information. Not everyone will read all the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a library called [Sigar](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) out there that can do all those fancy things.

The sigar jar can be called 'standalone' to explore the system:

```
$ java -jar sigar.jar
sigar> free
             total       used       free
Mem:       8388608    7940428     448180
-/+ buffers/cache:    5872060    2516548
Swap:       262144      95296     166848
RAM:        8192MB
```

For this to work, you also need the respective .dll or .so in the classpath

In [RHQ-project](http://rhq-project.org/) we use Sigar for many of those statistics - you can browse the code [here](http://git.fedorahosted.org/git?p=rhq/rhq.git;a=tree;f=modules/core/native-system;hb=HEAD).

Comment: How we can get exact RAM size using Siger?

Answer (score 7):

> ***How its possible through java?***

Generally, this is *not possible* to do in Java. You would have to go through an external program (see `ProcessBuilder`) or through a native library (written in for instance C++).

You could do

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

to get the OS architecture though. This gives `"amd64"` on my machine.

[The page here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110425082310/http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/io/30properties_and_preferences/40sysprops/10sysprop.html) lists a few other system properties too, but these seem to be VM specific though:

```
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
```